# How to fix this implicit error in my Ruby code

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5, chef-infra, chef-recipe

In this line I am getting error

```
node.default['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['ip_address'] = nodes.first('ipaddress').to_i
```

getting this error

```
Recipe Compile Error in /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/aem_dispatcher_cookbook/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================
TypeError --------- no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

Getting same if I remove `.to_i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One layer of your data might have array but you are expecting as hash.

See examples:

```
hash = { foo: [{ bar: "baz" }]}
=>  hash[:foo][:bar]
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

```
hash = { foo: [{ bar: "baz" }]}
=>  hash[:foo].first[:bar]
"baz"
```

Comment: Actually i am trying to get a ip address of other system in chef code ```publish_vm = 'apvrp27560'
  nodes = search(:node, 'hostname:publish_vm')
 node.default['aem_dispatcher_cookbook']['ip_address'] = nodes.first('ipaddress')
``` This is my code i tried your way but not getting can you check this